# Get Notification Title Android

Tags: java, android, notifications

How could I get the Notification Title of the notification ?

Here's my code :

**-From Notification Service** :

```
resultIntent= new Intent(NotificationService.this, StartNAFromNS.class);
                        resultIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, underestood_name.replace("__", " "));
```

**-From StartNAFromNS :**

```
String text = this.getIntent().getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE);
```

When doing this with only 1 notification, I get the correct title. However, if my application sends 2 notifications, I will get the title of the second notification.

How could I get the proper notification title ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notification `id` should be unique within your application.

> If a notification with the same `id` has already been posted by your
>   application and has not yet been canceled, it will be replaced by the
>   updated information.

```
NotificationManager notiManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);    
notiManager.notify(UNIQUE_ID, notification);
```

If you are using `PendingIntent.getActivity()` method, use different `requestCode` for different notification:

```
Intent resultIntent= new Intent(NotificationService.this, StartNAFromNS.class);
resultIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, underestood_name.replace("__", " "));    

PendingIntent pI = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, REQUEST_CODE, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Hope this will help!

Answer (score 9):

By extending `NotificationListenerService` and using its `onNotificationPosted` method in our class we will be able to get notification title, text and package name. Using notification package we get its app icon, app name and many more.

```
public class MyNotification extends NotificationListenerService {
    Context context;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        context = getApplicationContext();
    }
    @Override
    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        // We can read notification while posted.
    for (StatusBarNotification sbm : MyNotification.this.getActiveNotifications()) {
            String title = sbm.getNotification().extras.getString("android.title");
            String text = sbm.getNotification().extras.getString("android.text");
            String package_name = sbm.getPackageName();
        Log.v("Notification title is:", title);
        Log.v("Notification text is:", text);
        Log.v("Notification Package Name is:", package_name);
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: But how can I read the notification that was just closed (and that launched an intent) ? Because this code doesn't allow me to identify the title of the notification that was just clicked

Comment: Check this documentation help it out for your queries (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html)

Answer (score 0):

This code properly working for the fcm. We can send a message and title from the fcm console or server. The notification received by the registered mobile app.

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived (String from, Bundle data) {
    //Getting the message from the bundle
long dateTime = data.getLong("google.sent_time");
Bundle notificationBundle = data.getBundle("notification");
    String message = notificationBundle.getString("body");
    String title = notificationBundle.getString("title");

    //Displaying a notiffication with the message
    sendNotification(title, message);
}
```

//The following method is generating a notification and displaying the notification

```
private void sendNotification(String title, String message) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("message", message);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    int requestCode = 0;
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, requestCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    NotificationCompat.Builder noBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21)
        noBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    else
        noBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_small);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0, noBuilder.build()); //0 = ID of notification
}
```

Comment: The thing is, if I use sendNotification() more than one time, the extra is overwritten by the last message so I am not able to get the title of the first notification